# what is the legality behind "openMW" ( an open source implementation of morrowind)

Tags: legal, distribution

knowing bethesda those people probably sue hard....yet there is an open source implementation of morrowind which is actually quite good.
but that question remains, what is the legality behind all of this?
is it legal to distribute a free open-source implementation/adaptation of a videogame?

Comment: I don't know the details of openmw, but copyright/ip generally covers assets related stuff (graphics, models, audio, etc.). Not code. If OpenMW does not distribute any copyrighted assets (and assumes each user has a copy of the game, with the assets), it would be hard for Bethesda to have grounds to sue for anything. Quake code was released like this. If you wanted to play, you had to provide your own assets, assuming you owned the game.

Answer (score 3):

The OpenMW project maintains a FAQ page at https://openmw.org/faq/#bethesda_legal where the legality issue is dealt with.

> ### Does Bethesda Softworks approve of this project? Won’t you guys have legal problems?
>
> Bethesda Softworks is well aware of OpenMW and has given us approval to continue working on it, so long as certain conditions are followed.
>
> We had a long email conversation with Matt Grandstaff which can be read on the wiki. There was a misunderstanding as to what OpenMW is (a new game engine) and isn’t (a Morrowind port) that was cleared up. Bethesda Softworks has asked us to not promote any images or videos of OpenMW running Morrowind on Android or other mobile platforms, and we agreed to comply with this request. Anything else, is fair game, such as displaying videos of OpenMW running the OpenMW-Template on Android on the blog.
>
> We do not condone, nor are responsible, for other websites that show (in images or video) Morrowind running on an Android device.

The Bethesda emails are quite lengthy and numerous so I'll link them rather than quote them: https://wiki.openmw.org/index.php?title=Bethesda_Emails

> is it legal to distribute a free open-source implementation/adaptation of a videogame?

This is a more general question, and the most appropriate answer to "is is legal to..." questions is "ask a lawyer".

In this case, the developers have approval, in other cases a game engine may be open-sourced but the game assets may remain under a commercial license, other cases may be entirely different. So if you have a specific case in mind, check the licensing terms and if you have doubts, ask a lawyer.